# A page doesn't display with expected jQuery plugin online but locally works flawlessly

Tags: jquery

My contact us page uses jQuery plugin to display background navigation effects. Oddly I found it doesn't work as it is on localhost.WHat could be the error?

> checked console in chrome,it says certain images are missing but I found they exist in FTP.
>   Permision for contact-us.php(the problematic page) is 644 in ftp.

I did use jQuery.noConflict for this plugin script as I'm using about 3 jQueries in this very page.

Kindly advise.

The console error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/css/images/dock-bg.gif

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/images/1.jpg

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

Comment: 3 jQueries?!?! that's chaos. Sounds like maybe you just forgot to upload a file? or is the site possibly living in a sub directory? Are the src="" values for the js files starting with "/" or not? Use chrome and look at console I bet there is a network error saying one of the js files couldn't be loaded.

Comment: start by reconciling all the path problems.... look in network tab of browser console. If browser can't get the files....there is a path issue. Also check all script errors thrown in console

Comment: Also, look there for other errors and report back if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @Lenny ,above I added the console errors. But I think they wont affect the jQuery from working properly.Please advise!

Comment: Just posted an answer. It's just a matter of images in the wrong directories or mis-named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dock-bg is looking inside of the css directory like this which is a 404

```
http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/css/images/dock-bg.gif

it should be:

http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/images/dock-bg.gif
```

For the other it's a capitalization issue. You are probably testing on windows (which is not case sensitive) and you've deployed on linux which IS case sensitive

```
It's looking for:
http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/images/1.jpg

which doesn't exist the actual file can be found here (capital JPG):
http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/images/1.JPG
```

Comment: ,you're right..im using window to test and running on Linux..But I'm just wondering how this can affect the jQuery since both  images doesn't needed for that particular page?

Comment: Fix the error and see if it goes away. I'm just guessing, but it seems to me like maybe jQuery tries to load that first image (is 1.jpg the first image in your slide show?) and then when it fails it doesn't continue. There is a good chance it does something along the lines of setting the image and then starting the slideshow onLoad. Since it never actually loads the slideshow never starts. Again, just guessing.